# Deserialization issue accessing Redis from two different microservices

Tags: redis, spring-data-redis

Im trying to access same redis instance from two microservices using spring-data-redis.  I am having deserialization issues.

Imagine you have redis instance and two microservices are trying to access it.  For simplicity sake, imagine a UserRepository class and a User class that is stored in redis.

Here is what Im seeing

1) If I write to redis from microservice A and call userRepository.findAll() from microservice A, everything works and the data returns.

2) If I write to redis from microservice B and call userRepository.findAll() from microservice B, everything works and the data returns.

3) If I write to redis from microservice A and call userRepository.findAll() from microservice B, it returns NULL.

The RedisHash class is shared by both microservices, each having it's own class.  What I'm suspecting is the problem is the "_class" field that gets appended to the redis hash and when it tries to deserialize it, it gives it problems.

The @RedisHash are identical in fields but DIFFERENT in packages for both microservices.

Is there a way to resolve this by either removing _class or implementing custom serializers?

```java
@Getter
@AllArgsConstructor
@RedisHash("user")
public class User implements Serializable {
    @Id
    String userId;
    String jwtToken;
}


@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, String> {
    List<User> findAll();
}
```

To return data and not null

Comment: @RedisHash("qualifier") : qualifier should match to deserialize.

Comment: Both microservices use @RedisHash("user"), still doesn't deserialize.